How do we define an explicit $n$-dimensional injective function that follows specific criteria?
Motivation: I want an equation which distinguishes congruent sequences of bounded sets, using a real number, based on their location in the $n$-dimensional plane with respect to point $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$: e.g.,
$$(F_r^{\star})_{r\in\mathbb{N}}=([-r,r]\times[-r,r])_{r\in\mathbb{N}}$$
$$(F_j^{\star\star})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}=([-j+1,j+1]\times[-j-1,j-1])_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$$
$$C=(.5,-.5)$$
For each $r\in\mathbb{N}$, the average of $F_r^{\star}$ is $(0,0)$ and for each $j\in\mathbb{N}$, the average of $F_j^{\star\star}$ is $(1,-1)$: i.e., both have the same distance from $(.5,-.5)$.

Now, suppose we define Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra such that:
$$\text{Avg}(F_r^{\star})=\frac{1}{\lambda(F_r^{\star})}\int_{F_r^{\star}}(x_1,x_2)\,d\lambda$$
$$\text{Avg}(F_j^{\star\star})=\frac{1}{\lambda(F_j^{\star\star})}\int_{F_j^{\star\star}}(x_1,x_2)\,d\lambda$$
and we define $n$-d Euclidean distance $d(P,Q)$ for points $P,Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$
My question is for arbitrary, congruent sequences of rectangles $(F_r^{\star})_{r\in\mathbb{N}}$ to $(F_j^{\star\star})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$:

How we define an injective $2$-dimensional function
$f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$ (i.e., $C$ is a chosen point in $\mathbb{R}^2$):

If $d(\text{Avg}(F_r^{\star}),C)< d(\text{Avg}(F_j^{\star\star}),C)$, then $f(\text{Avg}(F_r^{\star})-C)< f(\text{Avg}(F_j^{\star\star})-C)$
If $d(\text{Avg}(F_r^{\star}),C)> d(\text{Avg}(F_j^{\star\star}),C)$, then $f(\text{Avg}(F_r^{\star})-C)>f(\text{Avg}(F_j^{\star\star})-C)$
If $d(\text{Avg}(F_r^{\star}),C)=d(\text{Avg}(F_j^{\star\star}),C)$, then $f(\text{Avg}(F_r^{\star})-C)\neq f(\text{Avg}(F_j^{\star\star})-C)$


Note, $f$ is injective so the output distinguishes each congruent sequence of rectangles.
Specfically, for sequences of arbitrary, congruent sequences of $n$-dimensional boxes $(F_r^{\star})_{r\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(F_j^{\star\star})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ where:
$$\text{Avg}(F_r^{\star})=\frac{1}{\lambda(F_r^{\star})}\int_{F_r^{\star}}(x_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,x_n)\,d\lambda$$
$$\text{Avg}(F_j^{\star\star})=\frac{1}{\lambda(F_j^{\star\star})}\int_{F_j^{\star\star}}(x_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,x_n)\,d\lambda$$

How do we define an explicit injective $n$-dimensional function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$ where (i.e., $C$ is a chosen point in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$):

If $d(\text{Avg}(F_r^{\star}),C)< d(\text{Avg}(F_j^{\star\star}),C)$, then $f(\text{Avg}(F_r^{\star})-C)< f(\text{Avg}(F_j^{\star\star})-C)$
If $d(\text{Avg}(F_r^{\star}),C)> d(\text{Avg}(F_j^{\star\star}),C)$, then $f(\text{Avg}(F_r^{\star\star})-C)>f(\text{Avg}(F_j^{\star\star})-C)$
If $d(\text{Avg}(F_r^{\star}),C)=d(\text{Avg}(F_j^{\star\star}),C)$, then $f(\text{Avg}(F_r^{\star})-C)\neq f(\text{Avg}(F_j^{\star\star})-C)$


